# React-Redux State not gettig updated/rendered

Tags: javascript, react-redux

Good afternoon,

I have been trying my hand at composition after following some tutorials. However I am at a dead end right now.

Whenever I try to update the state it doesnt get updated. Its strange because I have been able to update states before. I am afraid I am overlooking an error I made while trying to make things work.

The currentpage state is supposed to get updated and then render a new page on the screen, Im not sure if this is the correct way to this. So I am open to feedback regarding that aswel.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

reducer:

```
const pageLists = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_PAGE_LIST':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: action.id,
        }
      ];
    case 'NEXT_PAGE':
      console.log(action.id);
      console.log(action.nextPageId);
      return state.map((pageLists, index) => {
        console.log(index);
        if (index === action.id) {
          console.log("Next page succes")
          return Object.assign({}, pageLists, {
            currentpage: action.nextPageId
          })
        }
        return pageLists
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default pageLists
```

Container page-list

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Page from '../components/Page.jsx';
import {addPage} from '../actions/addPage.js'
import {nextPage} from '../actions/nextPage.js'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import _ from 'lodash';

class PageList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentpage: 0,
    };
  }

  renderList() {
    if(this.props.item){
      return (
        <div>
          <RaisedButton label="Next Page" onClick={() => this.props.nextPage(this.props.index, this.state.currentpage)}></RaisedButton>
          <Page key={this.props.item.id} index={this.props.item.id}>
            {this.props.item.title}
            {this.props.item.desc}
          </Page>
        </div>
      );
    }else{
      return(
        <p>No Pages</p>
      )
    }
  }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <RaisedButton label="Add new Page" onClick={() => this.props.addPage("Titel Page", "Page Beschrijving")}></RaisedButton>
            <ul>
                {this.renderList()}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

// Get apps state and pass it as props to PageList
//      > whenever state changes, the PageList will automatically re-render
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        pageLists: state.pageLists,
        item: _.find(state.pages, 'id', ownProps.currentpage)
    };
}

// Get actions and pass them as props to to PageList
//      > now PageList has this.props.selectPage
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({addPage: addPage, nextPage: nextPage}, dispatch);
}

// We don't want to return the plain PageList (component) anymore, we want to return the smart Container
//      > PageList is now aware of state and actions
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(PageList);
```

component survey.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {updateSurveyText} from '../actions/updateSurveyText.js'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PageList from '../containers/page-list.js';
import {addPageList} from '../actions/addPageList.js'

class Survey extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editing : false,
    };
    this.edit = this.edit.bind(this);
    this.save = this.save.bind(this);
    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
  }

  renderList(){
    console.log("page id =" + this.props.index);
    {this.props.addPageList()}
    return(
      <PageList key={this.props.index} index={this.props.index}>
      </PageList>);
  }

  edit() {
    this.setState({editing: true});
  }

  remove() {
    console.log('delete');
    this.props.deleteFromBoard(this.props.index)
  }

  save() {
    var title = this.refs.newTitle.value;
    var desc = this.refs.newDesc.value;
    console.log(this.props.index);
    this.props.updateSurveyText(title, desc, this.props.index);
    this.setState({editing: false});
  }

  renderNormal(){
    return(
      <div className="surveyContainer">
        <div className="surveyTitle">{this.props.children[0]}</div>
        <div className="surveyDesc">{this.props.children[1]}</div>
        <button onClick={this.edit} className="button-primary">Edit</button>
        <button onClick={this.remove} className="button-primary">Remove</button>
        {this.renderList()}
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderForm(){
    return(
      <div className="surveyContainer">
        <textarea ref="newTitle" defaultValue={this.props.children[0]}></textarea>
        <textarea ref="newDesc" defaultValue={this.props.children[1]}></textarea>
        <button onClick={this.save} className="button-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render(){
      if(this.state.editing){
        return this.renderForm();
      }else{
        return this.renderNormal();
      }
  }
}

// Get apps state and pass it as props to SurveyList
//      > whenever state changes, the SurveyList will automatically re-render
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        surveys: state.surveys
    };
}

// Get actions and pass them as props to to SurveyList
//      > now SurveyList has this.props.selectSurvey
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({updateSurveyText: updateSurveyText, addPageList: addPageList}, dispatch);
}

// We don't want to return the plain SurveyList (component) anymore, we want to return the smart Container
//      > SurveyList is now aware of state and actions
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Survey);
```

action nextPage.js:

```
export const nextPage = (id, nextPageId) => ({
  type: 'NEXT_PAGE',
  id: id,
  nextPageId: nextPageId+1
})
```

Comment: So I noticed that it is probably due to my constructor that sets the currentpage ot 0. However I dont know where to keep track of the currentpage. Any advice?

Comment: in reducer you are maintaining the state for whole app, so if you updating the currentpage in reducer, then you should not have your own defined currentpage in PageList Component, try use this.props.currentpage to get current value, and use nextPage to maintain currentpage